# MongoDB in Python: get specific value out of result in aggregate query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find the average score of posts in a database using MongoDB in python and I have done the query correctly but I wish to isolate the numeric value of the average from the result to use in other calculations but am unsure how to do that as the result I get is something like this:

```
{'_id': {'OwnerId': '24', 'PostType': '1'}, 'Score': 1.3333333333333333}
```

I simply want the 1.3333 from Score only.

The code for my query is:

```
group = {"$group":{"_id":{"OwnerId":"$OwnerUserId", "PostType":"$PostTypeId"}, "Score":{"$avg":"$Score"}}}
match = {"$match":{"OwnerUserId":uid}}
questionsScoreAverage = db.Posts.aggregate([match, group])
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this and would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two choices; either add a `$project` stage to the aggregate query, or simply select the `Score` dictionary element of the returned value, e.g.

```
for item in questionsScoreAverage :
    item.get('Score')
```